# Handling HTML5 videos in Android webView play fullscreen

Tags: android, video, webview, fullscreen

I am having issue with android webView videos in fullscreen. I have overriden the methods onShowCustomView and onHideCustomView as below, but the screen turn black upon expand but sound can be heard. What could be the issue.

```
private FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mContentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.streamVideoLayout);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(getApplicationContext());
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);
        view.setLayoutParams(LayoutParameters);

        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // Show the content view.
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever managed to fix it?